# Wordpress: display posts in menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

There is an issue with wordpress menu, I'll be very grateful if you help me.

See please screenshot.

[image]

Menu item "Destinations" is a category. "Elbrus 5642", "Baikal lake", is sub categories for 'Destinations'. And in every sub category I need to show posts for that sub category.
I thought to do it manually in code, e.g. call posts in sub category "Elbrus 5642" with query posts. But that way I need to every time change my code when I add or remove sub categories. Is there any method, which allow to automate this process, e.g. I adding some sub category in menu admin panel, creating some posts for that sub category and they are automatically added in menu?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Of course, give me a few minutes I'll add it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is http://jsfiddle.net/2jqtbgmp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts-in-custom-menu/) plugin, I think it's what you need.

Comment: Oh man, I solved that 6 months ago, but without plugin. Thank you for answer.